# c pointers and javascript

Tags: javascript, c, arrays, pointers

I have been working on a conversion of a C code into javascript. But they just don't return the same data.

I have an idea on how to handle the pointers. In javascript I'll create an array.

> Note: This are not the full code, only partials

Origin:

```
// file.h
unsigned char m_aucState0[256]; 
unsigned char m_aucState[256]; 
unsigned char m_ucI; 
unsigned char m_ucJ; 
unsigned char* m_pucState1; 
unsigned char* m_pucState2;

// file.c
unsigned char *pucKeyData

for(i=0; i<256; i++)   
{   
    m_pucState1 = m_aucState0 + i;   
    m_ucJ += *m_pucState1 + *(pucKeyData+m_ucI);   
    m_pucState2 = m_aucState0 + m_ucJ;   
    //Swaping   
    m_ucTemp = *m_pucState1;   
    *m_pucState1 = *m_pucState2;   
    *m_pucState2 = m_ucTemp;   
    m_ucI = (m_ucI + 1) % iKeyLen;   
}   
memcpy(m_aucState, m_aucState0, 256);
```

Javascript:

```
// buffer or array???
this.m_aucState0 = new Buffer(256)
this.m_aucState = new Buffer(256)

this.m_ucI
this.m_ucJ

this.m_pucState1 = []
this.m_pucState2 = []


for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
  this.m_pucState1 = this.m_aucState0 + i
  this.m_ucJ += this.m_pucState1[0] + (pucKeyData[0] + this.m_ucI)
  this.m_pucState2 = this.m_aucState0 + this.m_ucJ

  //Swaping
  this.m_ucTemp = this.m_pucState1[0]
  this.m_pucState1[0] = this.m_pucState2[0]
  this.m_pucState2[0] = this.m_ucTemp

  this.m_ucI = (this.m_ucI + 1) % iKeyLen
}

this.m_aucState.copy(this.m_aucState0, 0, 0, 256)
```

So my idea is because a pointer returns an address, that address contains the first byte of the pointer data. So if in an array I could just also point to the first index of the array right?

Is what I did above right?

---

Just for context let me add 1 function:

Javascript:

```
Crypt.prototype.setup = function(pucKeyData, iKeyLen) {
  if (iKeyLen < 1)
    throw new Error("Key Length should be at least 1")

  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    this.m_aucState0[i] = i

  this.m_ucI = 0
  this.m_ucJ = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    this.m_pucState1 = this.m_aucState0 + i
    this.m_ucJ += this.m_pucState1[i] + (pucKeyData[i] + this.m_ucI)
    this.m_pucState2 = this.m_aucState0 + this.m_ucJ

    //Swaping
    this.m_ucTemp = this.m_pucState1[i]
    this.m_pucState1[i] = this.m_pucState2[i]
    this.m_pucState2[i] = this.m_ucTemp

    this.m_ucI = (this.m_ucI + 1) % iKeyLen
  }

  this.m_aucState.copy(this.m_aucState0, 0, 0, 256)

  //Initialize Indexes
  this.m_ucI = 0
  this.m_ucJ = 0

  //Initialization Finished
  this.m_bInit = true
}
```

CPP:

```
void CArcfourPRNG::SetKey(unsigned char *pucKeyData, int iKeyLen)   
{   
    if(iKeyLen < 1)   
        throw exception("Key Length should be at least 1");   
    int i;   
    for(i=0; i<256; i++)   
        m_aucState0[i] = i;   
    m_ucI = 0;   
    m_ucJ = 0;   
    for(i=0; i<256; i++)   
    {   
        m_pucState1 = m_aucState0 + i;   
        m_ucJ += *m_pucState1 + *(pucKeyData+m_ucI);   
        m_pucState2 = m_aucState0 + m_ucJ;   
        //Swaping   
        m_ucTemp = *m_pucState1;   
        *m_pucState1 = *m_pucState2;   
        *m_pucState2 = m_ucTemp;   
        m_ucI = (m_ucI + 1) % iKeyLen;   
    }   
    memcpy(m_aucState, m_aucState0, 256);   
    //Initialize Indexes   
    m_ucI = 0;   
    m_ucJ = 0;   
    //Initialization Finished   
    m_bInit = true;   
}
```

---

What is the difference of `m_pucState1` and `*m_pucState1` in this:

```
m_pucState1 = m_aucState + m_ucI;   
m_ucJ += *m_pucState1;
```

Comment: @chris those are just partial codes. not everything. just the relevant.

Comment: Java arrays in C should technically be a, in this case, Buffer**. Everything is a reference, include the array. So, we have a pointer to the array object, that points to other references. Use std::array or std::vector, not a raw array. You should really think about whats going on as a whole here, and don't just try to convert everything line by line, it'll be a lot easier.

Comment: @Ben I'm actually working with javascript and c. Yes I'm also trying that. But generally I need to understand how pointers really work here. As I'm not very good with it.

Comment: pucKeyData seems to be uninitialised when you use it.

Comment: @Ben Its the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, there are typed buffer objects: http://www.javascripture.com/ArrayBuffer

You will also find something about the ctypes collection, but in my understanding they are used only for native OS library calls.

Also, I don't know a native JS Buffer object like you mention it. There is one in NodeJS, but I don't know its features.

If you insist of translating your code one-by-one, then these typed buffer objects may greatly support you. I think it's not a good way as while translating from C to Javascript, your terminology alters anyway. It alters from *adding long pointer values* to *forming array indices*.

Here is one problem example in your translation:

In C, you write:

```
m_ucJ += *m_pucState1 + *(pucKeyData+m_ucI);
```

In Javascript, you write:

```
this.m_ucJ += this.m_pucState1[0] + (pucKeyData[0] + this.m_ucI);
```

The brackets in the C term make `m_ucI` altering the address. So in Javascript this should rather be in the square brackets, somehow like this:

```
this.m_ucJ += this.m_pucState1[0] + pucKeyData[0 + this.m_ucI];
```

and then you can skip the "0 +". This shows how one-by-one translation between such different languages is full of traps.

So let's assume that we will use the simplest Javascript object, which is the array `[]`. Then this is my suggestion. It's a draft, but it should give you a thorough idea:

```
// Define arrays
var aState0 = []; // m_aucState0
var aState = []; // m_aucState

// Define helpers
var state1Index; // *m_pucState1
var state2Index; // *m_pucState2 
var i; // m_uci. There is no such thing as "uc" in Javascript.
var j; // m_ucj 
var iLoop; // i in loop.

// It's readable to have this constant.
var bufferLength = 255;

// Somewhere we need:
var keyData;
var temp;
var iKeyLen;


// Just for here, give the array a size. So it's done in Javascript. 
// Alternatively, fill it with 256 values from anywhere.
aState0[bufferLength] = 0;
// console.log(state0.length) will now print 256

// ...
// init i, j, iKeyLen ... 
// ...


for (iLoop = 0; iLoop <= bufferLength; iLoop++) {

    // This:
    // m_pucState1 = m_aucState0 + i;   
    // m_ucJ += *m_pucState1 + *(pucKeyData+m_ucI); 
    // becomes:
    state1Index = iLoop;
    j += aState0[state1Index] + keyData[i]; 

    // This: 
    // m_pucState2 = m_aucState0 + m_ucJ; 
    // becomes:
    state2Index = j;

    // This:
    // m_ucTemp = *m_pucState1;   
    // *m_pucState1 = *m_pucState2;   
    // *m_pucState2 = m_ucTemp;  
    // becomes:
    temp = aState0[state1Index];
    aState0[state1Index] = aState0[state2Index];
    aState0[state2Index] = temp;

    // This:
    // m_ucI = (m_ucI + 1) % iKeyLen; 
    // becomes:
    i = (i+1) % iKeyLen;    

}

// this:
// memcpy(m_aucState, m_aucState0, 256); 
// would be a clone. So you'd need jQuery or else. But you can simply write:
for (index in state0) {
    state[index] = state0[index];
}
```

Finally, you can drop `j` as it is equal to `state2Index`, and `state1Index` equal to `iLoop`.

But this is a puzzle where you will probably have to use paper and pencil and to draw some boxes and arrows to get clear with.

Hth :-)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now. anyways this is for a server. I'm using node.js :)

Comment: I actually got the C++ codes [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/sourcecode/crypt/457839/ArcfourPRNG.cpp__.htm). It's short but I'm also having a problem with the `RAND()` function. Would you check that? I think thats the only one lacking for this to be all right.

Comment: I added some clarifications to the end of my question. can you check that?

Comment: The difference between 1) `m_pucState1 = m_aucState + m_ucI;` and 2) `m_ucJ += *m_pucState1;` is: in 1), you have a pointer called `m_aucState`, and you add an offset called `m_ucI` to that pointer. So you create a new address. Then you let `m_pucState1` point to that address. In 2), you take the address `m_pucState1` and dereference it with the star `*`. With the star, you get the value stored in the memory cell that is addressed by `m_pucState1`. Then you add this value to `m_ucJ`.

Comment: What is the purpose of RAND() in this context in short words, and what is going wrong with the code? There is too much guessing and assuming for me.